# display jfreecharts using servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jfreechart

I have a scenario where I need to display charts(generated using jfreecharts) converted it into a png image and then display them using servlets.

When the chart code extends either ApplicationFrame or Jframe I see the following exception when I display it using servlets :

```
java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:317)
at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:419)
at javax.swing.JFrame.(JFrame.java:194)
```

I read through a couple of places and this seems to be because of the ApplicationFrame and JFrame would cause this error.

If i pass just the chart object this throws a

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null 'chart' argument.
    org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(ChartUtilities.java:181)
    org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(ChartUtilities.java:136)
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ChartUtilities` is the right choice; streams are supported, too. One approach requires [*Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html), but I've also gotten it to work with VNC.

Addendum: here's a related forum [thread](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1012&hilit=X11+DISPLAY+BufferedImage).

Comment: thank you for this information I am atleast able to move beyond this exception to another one

Comment: You are welcome; don't hesitate to open a new question as the need arises.

Comment: sorry to re-open this  but even after setting the property java.awt.headless to true I am still seeing this exception again. any more clues or ideas ?

Comment: I recall having to set the property in one of the servlet container's configuration files. Which container are you using?

Comment: i tried setting it in the java servlet code System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true"); do you think it is better if I set this in the catalina.sh file ?

Comment: Tomcat? Yes, I set it in `catalina.sh`.

Comment: I have used this command to set the value  export CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true" done the same with JAVA_OPTS and checked too , the exception is

Comment: @trashgod let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1141/discussion-between-bhavya-ph-and-trashgod)

Comment: I was facing an issue even after adding the properties in the corresponding files, as I was trying to use ApplicationFrame and JFrame in the headless mode

Answer (score 1):

I will explain you in simple way as I faced the same problem as i was new.

Steps

1. Create a servlet
2. In doPost create outputstream
3. set content type to text/png
4. Create datasets
5. set values to dataset
6. create instance of jfreechart and call createchart(the chart you wanna use) using ChartFqactory.
7. finally call WriteChartAsPNG using ChartUtilities and pass the Jfreechart instance,outputstream,width,height.

DONE:

Sample below

```
 package polo;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.data.general.DefaultPieDataset;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class PieChartDemo1Serv
 */
public class PieServ extends HttpServlet implements useme {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public PieServ() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doPost(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        response.setContentType("image/png");   

        ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

        DefaultPieDataset pieDataset = new DefaultPieDataset();

        pieDataset.setValue("In-Network ", .80);

        pieDataset.setValue("Out-of-Network ", .20);



        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart("", pieDataset, true, true, false);

ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, 202, 182);
    System.out.println("done23");

    }


}
```

Now I know you what further.Study Pieplots/Legends to setup border and formatting.You can do a lot further.